# For $X$ independent of $Y$, how can we show that if $XZ \sim YZ$, implies that $X \sim Y$?

Tags: probability, statistics

If we have that $X$ is independent of $Y$, how can we show that if $XZ \sim YZ$, that is, $XZ$ has the same distribution as $YZ$, that we can also infer that $X \sim Y$? I am trying to figure out the measure theoretic way of doing it but am not sure how to work with Borel sets in that manner. Would anyone have any hints? Thanks!

Comment: There is at least one exception.

Comment: This is not ture. Let $X=1$, $Y=-1$, and $Z$ be any symmetric random variable.